# Wifi config on raspian jessie getting DHCP lease but no DNS

Tags: wireless-networking, dns, dhcp, raspberry-pi, debian-jessie

I'm having this issue on raspian jessie where the wifi interface is connecting to the router, getting an address by DHCP, getting the correct gateway, but DNS is not working. Can ping 8.8.8.8 for example but not google.com.

When I connect other devices to the router the DNS works fine so I know it is not a fault of the router. (Also tried connecting to a different router and still had the issue).

/etc/network/interfaces:

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

wpa_supplicant.conf:

```
country=US
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
network={
    ssid="blah blah"
    psk="skdhfks!"
}
```

Output of route -e

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlan0
10.0.0.0        *               255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
```

I don't want to hack this by forcing DNS to use 8.8.8.8 because this will be used in a place that may have local services so it needs to access local dns information from the router.

Comment: Please add which DHCP client do you use - unfortunetly there are multiple ones, not all are set to alter `/etc/resolv.conf` automatically.

Comment: Please clarify, what do you need to know and how can I find out?

Comment: DNS server used by system is specified in /etc/resolv.conf file. DHCP client program should overwrite nameserver in this file with IP of the router. However some don't do this by default. Tell me which client do you use (preferably which package provides it). Following command should provide answer: `dpkg -S /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`

Comment: isc-dhcp-client

Comment: Hey thanks! I thought I had tried `inet dhcp` but i tried again and now it all works! If you put that as an answer I will accept it :)

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to restart network or reboot the first time - glad i could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isc-dhcp-client` should set name servers automatically (by overriding `/etc/resolv.conf` ). Try the following:

1. Set the line `iface wlan0 inet manual` in `/etc/network/interfaces`  to `iface wlan0 inet dhcp`
2. Verify that `domain-name-servers` is in the `request` line in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`.

Comment: Sadly, after a reboot, the problem came back.

Comment: Some combination of `ifup`, `ifdown` and a couple of `dhclient`s seems to fix it...

Comment: Thanks for the info. Perhaps running dhcp client from a service script (daemon) executed only after successful network setup could resolve it permanently. It's definetly posible in systemd, not so sure about the old sysV anymore.